# Banner for Android TV app created in React Native using expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-manifest

I'd like to ask your advice. I am creating an Android TV app in React Native using expo. According to the documentation, the expo allows you to add assets for an icon or splash screen, but I couldn't find information anywhere about how to add assets for `android:banner`. Has anyone solved this? Thanks for the tips!

I tried to edit `AndroidManifest.xml`, but unfortunately I was not successful there.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem has been solved since version 0.0.5 of the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-tvos/config-tv package and the banner can be added